# Reading the measurement of the slope of a floor

Tags: floor

I have been told the slope of a floor is 2.5 degrees. How does that translate to the dropping of the floor so many inches in four feet?

Answer (score 5):

48 inches Tan(2.5 degrees) = 2.10 inches.

or a 4% slope.